# How to solve $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \frac{m}{n} > \frac{1}{cn^4}, \forall n \ge 1$?

Tags: number-theory

If $\frac{m}{n}$ is an irreducible fraction such that $1 > \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \frac{m}{n} > 0$, then there exists a constant $c > 0$ so that $$\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \frac{m}{n} > \frac{1}{cn^4}, \forall n \ge 1$$

From the first inequation we can show that $4n > m \ $ and $\ m > 2n$.

I was also intuitively thinking that as $n$ gets bigger and bigger $m$ can approximate $(\sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3})n$ better and better so then $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \frac{m}{n}$ tends to $0$.

Comment: Use that $a=\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3$ is the root of a fourth degree polynomial with integral coefficients

Comment: The statement is $\forall m \,\,\exists c \,\,\forall n$? Or $\exists c\,\, \forall m \,\,\forall n$?

Comment: @PeterFranek The latter is the correct statement.

Comment: The ambiguity of your question, as stated, shows why we like to see all quantifiers coming first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an old result of Liouville :https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation
It can be applied because your number $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is algebraic of degree $4$.